# Which control primitive should I use to avoid a syntax error during compilation?

Tags: netlogo

What I am attempting to do here is to make certain patches with certain colours either spawn or kill turtles and the road patches (colour grey) impose changes in headings on the turtles depending on what the user has selected in the interface.  I have used a while control primitive within my code however the compiler reports the error message: " If expected two inputs, a TRUE/ FALSE and a command block." I want the heading of the cars being spawned on the blue squares to remain 90 only when they are on the blue square and to change to whatever the user defines when the cars are travelling along the roads in-between the spawning and the killing patches. How should I change the while control primitive to prevent a compiler error? Would "if" be better suited to what I am trying to achieve?

```
 to edit-world-secondary

ask turtles-on patches with [pcolor = grey]
[control-movement]  

 ask patches with [pcolor = blue]
 [ crt 10[ init-car]]
 while [turtles-on patches with [pcolor = blue] [ set heading 90] 
 ]

 ask turtles-on patches with [pcolor = orange][process-sinks]

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change it to `ask`.

If what you want to do ask the turtles on blue patches to set their headings to 90

```
ask turtles with[pcolor = blue][set heading 90]
```

A strange but useful trait of NetLogo is the ability of turtles to access the variables of the patch it is on.

It is a good rule of thumb in NetLogo to avoid `while` loops they are are not culturally appropriate and usually can be better done with `ask`, `repeat`, `foreach`, `map` etc

If you want an agent set to do something every turn it is customary to ask them in your go.

If you are compelled to use `while` this is the syntax

```
while [ reporter ] [ commands]
```

(there are brackets around the reporter)

And the write up.

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#while

Comment: It is correct syntax but will cause your program to freeze if any turtles are on blue patches.(they will be setting their headings to 90 for eternity). use ask. Love ask. Ask is your friend.